# Strange Barcode Appearance in CMD (python), explanation?

Tags: python, runtime-error, barcode, barcode-scanner

Something very weird happened.  I'm experimenting with the split() method and parsing data.  When I printed my results to CMD there was a random barcode among the lines.  When I ran the program again, there was no barcode.

Any explanation / hypothesis?

```
file = open("dbuslog.txt", "r")
lines = file.readlines()


line = lines[0].split('=:')
line = ' '.join(line)
print ""
print line
line = line.split(' ->')
line = ''.join(line)

print ""
print line
line = line.split('=')
line = ' '.join(line)
print ""
print line
line = line.split(' ')
print ""
print line

dict = {}
if len(line)%2 == 0:
    index = 0
    while index < len(line)-1:
        dict[line[index]] = line[index+1]
        index += 2
else:
    print "SOMETHING IS WRONG, DID NOT PARSE CORRECTLY, ODD NUMBER OF ITEMS"
print ""
print dict

file.close()
```

Here is are the pictures:
The bottom one is the screen shot (I edited out my username - no other changes)
The upper one is our attempt to find a match.  When it is flipped horizontally it meets the specifications for ITF (Interleaved 2 of 5)

[image: Flipped and Scaled]

[image: Original]

Comment: One more upvote and you are able to post images...

Comment: You've not provided enough information. What are you parsing? What are you trying to accomplish? What are you expecting to see?

Comment: While I don't claim that there was no barcode -- if you can't reproduce the problem, then it's unlikely that we can.  And if we can't reproduce the problem, it's unlikely that we'll be able to give you any real help here...

Comment: I'm just parsing data for work, mostly words and small numbers.  I'm really just learning python so my goal was to learn about strings and the split() method - not really trying to accomplish anything.
I didn't expect to see it either, I wish I could have reproduced it, but I couldn't.  I'm just posting this to see if anyone has even an idea of how that's possible?

Comment: @Jordan what was in the file?

Comment: Probably a glitch in the console display. Move the scrollbar up and down to see if it disappears.

Comment: @iKlsR It was just words with some small numbers.  I can't share the text cause its from work, but it is like this:
"foo bar baz=:4.57 -> foo=:4.55 bar_baz=3"
A bunch of those lines and some dictonaries: "{"stuff":true,"stuff":"[gps coord]:}"

Comment: @angus It did disappear, but I wasn't paying attention to when/how

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the glyphs which correspond to the values between 219 and 223.

http://www.asciitable.com/

Your program was probably printing an ASCII string containing those sorts of values. So it looked like a barcode when printed to your terminal window.

It's not actually a barcode.

Comment: It's too standard to just be random ASCII characters.  In my edit I explain that it matches  ITF (Interleaved 2 of 5).  (I think it does, i'm no expert)